Shopware 6: Custom translations in en-GB.json not overriding default snippets
I'm having trouble overriding default Shopware 6 snippets with my custom translations in a plugin. Despite defining custom translations in my en-GB.json file, the default values are still being displayed.
Here's my en-GB.json file:
{
    "sw-customer": {
        "baseInfo": {
            "labelBoundSalesChannel": "Bound Sales Channel",
            "emptyBoundSalesChannel": "None"
        }
    }
}

And here's the relevant part of my Twig template (sw-customer-base-info):
{% block sw_customer_base_metadata_bound_sales_channel %}
    <sw-description-list>
        {% block sw_customer_base_metadata_bound_sales_channel_label %}
            <dt class="sw-customer-base-info__label sw-bound-sales-channel__label">
                {{ $tc('sw-customer.baseInfo.labelBoundSalesChannel') }}
            <sw-help-text :text="$tc('sw-customer.baseInfo.helpTextBoundSalesChannel')" />
        </dt>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block sw_customer_base_metadata_bound_saleschannel_content %}
        <dd class="sw-customer-base__label-bound-sales-channel">
            <template v-if="customer.boundSalesChannelId">
                {{ customer.salesChannel.translated.name }}
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                {{ $tc('sw-customer.baseInfo.emptyBoundSalesChannel') }}
            </template>
        </dd>
    {% endblock %}
</sw-description-list>
{% endblock %}

I expected to see 'Bound Sales Channel' as the label for labelBoundSalesChannel and 'None' for emptyBoundSalesChannel. However, I'm seeing 'Sales Channel' and 'All' respectively, which are the default values.
What am I missing? How can I get my custom translations to override the default snippets?
Environment:
Shopware version: [6.6.4.1]
PHP version: [8.2]
